# Xpath with XHTML namespaces on Selenium API Java

Tags: selenium, xpath, xhtml

i'm trying to find an element on a web page by using Xpath on Selenium API but it seems like Xpath on selenium doesn't find the element because of the XHTML namespaces.
Is there a way to find an element with XHTML on Selenium ?

Here is an exemple of my issue:

```
<document>
<xhtml:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xhtml:head>
<xhtml:body onload="initialiser();">
<xhtml:div align="center">
<xhtml:div align="left">
</xhtml:html>
</document>
```

I want to find my element without specify the namespace like //xhtml:div
Actually, i just want to use an Xpath like : //div

Comment: Which element do you want to find here?

Answer (score 1):

*(I know this question was asked almost a year ago, but it looks like existing answers do not answer the original question)*

Recent Selenium builds [now allow you to use the same prefix as in your document](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1694) with your XPath expressions. This was fixed in March 2015 and has meanwhile been accepted into the main branch. Not sure whether it is already in the current stable public release.

Since simple node tests like your suggestion, `/div`, won't work not even with a new selenium build, you may want to use `//*[local-name() = 'div']`, which will get you what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a wildcard for the namespace. Some something like: `//*:div[1]` would return the first `div` element.

Comment: No, this works only with XPath 2.0. Selenium supports whatever is in the browser, which currently is XPath 1.0.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to write Xpath for any webElement: 
1: writing absolute xPath 
2: writing relative xPath

If you write any absoulte xpath you have to proceed with html hierarchy and that is when you would require //xhtml...
but if you write relative xpaths, you don't need to define exact html hierarchy

so, Let say you want xpath to identify left div -  //div[@align='left']

Comment: How does this help the asker? The OP clearly has no problem with XPath in general. Besides, `//xhtml` does **not** require an absolute hierarchy, and frankly, neither relative or absolute XPath expressions do. It depends on the chosen **axis** per **axis step** whether you require to write an exact hierarchy or not